# Ways to store data in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, persistence

I am looking for ways to store data in a Windows Forms application in .NET.
I want to make the input data of a system persistent, so when I close my program and open it again, the data is retrieved.

Which ways of doing this exist besides creating a linked database?
Examples are gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are dozens of different ways to store data.  It completely depends on *what* data.  Is it:

- Just a couple of configuration values?  Use the built-in Settings library.
- Machine-wide configuration?  Use the registry.
- Transactional?  Use a relational database.
- Related but not transactional?  Use a lightweight database like SQLite or SQLCE.
- Structured but not related?  Use XML or JSON files.
- Somewhat structured and high in volume?  Use a NoSQL solution like MongoDB.

And so on... there are different solutions for every storage requirement and many projects make use of more than one at a time.

Comment: +1 for describing that there are many options - you don't just use XML for all app settings files.  Too many people use a single methodology for all purposes.

Comment: If you have data which is transactional, but not relational you can use the built-int ESENT database.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way would be to make use of XML.

[Using XML in C# in the simplest way](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/XMLReadWrite.aspx)

[Read/Write Xml document with FileStream](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0540__XML/ReadWriteXmldocumentwithFileStream.htm)

Comment: Oops astander!!, you beat me :)

Answer (score 1):

If your data is not mission critical (e.g. user preferences), you could just serialise your objects to file, and de-serialise them next time the app is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Examples? Do your homework yourself :)

Anyhow, possible ways are:

- Registry.
- Files. Like Microsoft Word does. Or like an ini file, like most games do for example for their settings
- Databaase

Which makes sense depends on what the application DOES and other scenarios around it. A fast answer is not really possible without knowing more.